# Enable Default Sound on FCM Push Notification for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set the default sound for a push notification sent and have the following message object to pass through.

```
var message = {
      notification: {
        title: "X",
        body: "X",
        sound: 'default'
      }          
      token: fcmToken
 };
```

I continue, however, to receive the following error in my cloud function log:

> Error sending message: Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown
>   name "sound" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.

I've tried placing the sound property under the notification object, apns-payload-aps object, and cannot seem to locate documentation on the correct syntax to activate the default sound on iOS.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insane, but for me, some reason in appdelegate the window variable was deleted and that resulted into this issue..

adding it back, sound works correctly now...

Comment: Do you think sound parameter is compulsory ??

Comment: What if there is no 'sound' parameter in aps object ? it will stop even default sound of push notification ? Currently, no sound is played in my push notification .. do you think this is because of no sound parameters ?
Is this compulsory > “sound” : “default” ?

Answer (score 7):

"sound" is not a valid key for the "notification" object in the message's structure.
"sound" is a platform specific key that you have to set under either "android" or "apns" object.

```
{
    notification: {
        title: "X",
        body: "X"
    },
    apns:{
        payload: {
            aps: {
                sound: "default"
            }
        }
    }
    token: fcmToken
}
```

Consult [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig) for more info

Comment: i thought i had already tried it, but what didn't result in an error was placing the sound: 'default' key value pair under the aps object, under the payload object, which is under the apns object. however - the sound still doesn't play when testing on my iphone though...any thoughts? @balsick

Comment: @Chris sorry man, I made a mistake in the structure I had previously posted. Check if it works now ;)

Comment: no worries, but it actually had to be under the aps object which is under both the payload and apns objects. any thoughts though on why the sound is still not triggering? when i send a manual message with the notification composer with sound enabled, my device does ring so im not sure if i necessarily have anything wrong setup in xcode..

Comment: @Chris I am also observing issue of no default sound when notification received. 
What if there is no 'sound' parameter in aps object ? it will stop even default sound of push notification ? Currently, no sound is played in my push notification .. do you think this is because of no sound parameters ?
Is this compulsory > “sound” : “default” ?

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed unfortunately I cannot find any information of what happens if no `sound`key is specified inside aps object. it looks like no sound is emitted if it is not specified, though. here's an apple doc link. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification#2943363